# Is there a way to override core Moodle forms to add more fields? like category form

Tags: php, moodle, moodle-api, moodle-theme

I'm trying to figure a way to add more fields to the **category** **form** in **Moodle**, is there a way to achieve that through **local plugins**? I have tried making a local plugin with the same file structure for **editcategory_form.php** and made a custom one with the same original file in addition to the new fields, the plugin gets recognized and installed and has it's own settings page that I can access but Moodle keeps serving me the original editcategory_form.php, how can I override it so it serves my copy of the form instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot extend the edit category form without making core changes to the Moodle code.

With a local plugin, you could extend the navigation on the category page to include a link to a custom form (with the extra settings you want to add), but there is no way to directly override the original form (without modifying the core code).

e.g. in local/myplugin/lib.php:

```
function local_myplugin_extend_settings_navigation(settings_navigation $nav, context $context) {
    if ($context->contextlevel == CONTEXT_COURSECAT) {
        $nav->add(get_string('customsettings', 'local_myplugin'), new moodle_url('/local/myplugin/customsettings.php', ['categoryid' => $context->instanceid]);
    }
}
```

(Example code written off the top of my head,so could easily have mistakes).

Comment: Extending the navigation settings will be on this page: course/management.php? and by link you mean like a button that will redirect me to the new custom form?

Comment: In the latest version of Moodle the navigation has been moved into tabs across the top of the page, so the link you insert should appear across the top of the page when the relevant category is selected (it might be hidden under 'More'). There will not be a button or icon created.